# Get list of all applications deployed on a weblogic server

Tags: java, python, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, wlst

Using the following code, I am able to connect to the weblogic server.
Now I want to get a list of all the applications deployed on the server.

listapplications() from the command prompt lists the applications, but I am not able to store the output into a variable when I execute interpreter.exec(listapplications()) because interpreter.exec returns a void. Any ideas on how can I store the applications list in a collection/array?

Any other alternative or leads would also help.

```
import org.python.util.InteractiveInterpreter;
import weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTInterpreter;

public class SampleWLST {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SampleWLST wlstObject = new SampleWLST();
        wlstObject.connect();
    }

    public void connect() {
        InteractiveInterpreter interpreter = new WLSTInterpreter();
        interpreter.exec("connect('username', 'password', 't3://localhost:8001')");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it. I captured the output of the wlst by redirect to a stream using setOut method of InteractiveInterpreter and wrote a scanner to read the stream in Java.

Hope this might help someone else.

```
ArrayList<String> appList = new ArrayList<String>();
Writer out = new StringWriter();
interpreter.setOut(out);
interpreter.exec("print listApplications()");   

StringBuffer results = new StringBuffer();
results.append(out.toString());

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(results.toString());
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    line = line.trim();
    if(line.equals("None"))
        continue;
    appList.add(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get all deployed articats which are deployed, you can use:

```
private void listAllDeployments(WebLogicDeploymentManager deployManager,
                                  Target targets[]) throws TargetException {
  if (deployManager != null && targets.length > 0) {
    print("Get Domain:" + deployManager.getDomain(), 0);
    TargetModuleID targetModuleID[] = deployManager.getAvailableModules(ModuleType.WAR, 
      targets);
    } else {
      System.out.print(
        "WebLogicDeploymentManager is either empty or targets are empty.Please check",
        1);
    }

  }
```

For creating deployer manager, you can use :

```
SessionHelper.getRemoteDeploymentManager(protocol,hostName, portString, adminUser, adminPassword);
```

Dependencies that you will need :

compile(group: 'com.oracle.weblogic', name: 'wlfullclient', version: '10.3.6.0', transitive: false)